# Validation errors in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if my application's buttons are pressed or not. The error I face is, even when the buttons are clicked all the alerts display. Attached is the code snippet, the variables are set by click of buttons.

I want the alert not to display if any of the values are selected,

```
var condition ; 
var clickable;     // GLOBAL VARIABLES

function clickMe1() 
{
    clickable = "Sell";
}

function clickMe2() 
{
    clickable = "Rent";
}

function condition1()
{
    condition="Excellent"
}

function condition2()
{
    condition="Good"
}

function condition3()
{
    condition="Fair"
}

function condition4()
{
    condition="New"
}



function display()    
{
    if (condition != "Excellent"||"New"||"Fair"||"Good")
    {
        alert( " Please enter the condition ");
    }
    if (clickable != "Sell"||"Rent")
    {
        alert("Please enter the Sell");
    }
    if (costSell === '')  
    {
        alert("Please select a Price ");
    }
    if ((condition === "Excellent"||"New"||"Fair"||"Good") && (clickable === "Selling"||"leasing")&&(!isNaN(costSell)))
    {
        // Do Something
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log("not added");
    }
    });
    }
    else
    {
        alert(" price is not a number"); 
    }
}
```

I also tried:

```
if(condition !='Excellent'|| condition!='New' || condition!='Fair'|| condition!='Good')
{
    alert( " Please enter the condition ");
}
if (clickable !='Sell'||'Rent' )
{
    alert("Please enter the Sell ");
```

Comment: Why do you put a space *before* the punctuators in your sentences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(condition !='Excellent'|| condition!='New' || condition!='Fair'|| condition!='Good')`

should be

`if (condition != 'Excellent' && condition != 'New' && condition != 'Fair' && condition != 'Good')​`

because your version triggers if the condition is any one of Excellent, New, Fair, or Good. The corrected line triggers when the condition is *not* one of those.

And

`if (clickable !='Sell'||'Rent' )`

should be

`if (clickable !='Sell' && clickable !='Rent' )`

because you can't make that shortcut of only using `clickable` once.

Comment: Thank you for your answer , But the purpose of my conditions are the alert should not display if any of the values are set

Answer (score 0):

`condition !="Excellent"||"New"||"Fair"||"Good"`

Conditions like this are your problem.

`condition !="Excellent" && condition != "New" ...`

^The solution

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you're testing multiple conditions without repeating the left-hand operand.

For example:

```
condition !="Excellent"||"New"||"Fair"||"Good"
```

It should be this:

```
condition != "Excellent" || condition != "New" || condition != "Fair" || condition !="Good"
```

Comment: @alex - You'll have to repeat the left-hand operand for each conditional every time. I just gave you an example of what code you must replace.